# How to create Azure IoT Hub device without Azure portal

Tags: c++, azure-iot-hub

I am working with a custom PCB (ESP32) and the firmware is written in C++. I am looking for a way to register a device without any human intervention.

Answer (score 1):

A device wouldn't normally register itself with IoT Hub. It would need access to the Service API. Two common scenarios of registering a device are:

1. Connect your device to [Azure Device Provisioning Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/about-iot-dps?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034); it can assign an IoT Hub to your device. You can either register a single device with DPS, or create group enrollments. It also depends on how your device authenticates with DPS/IoT Hub.
2. Create the registration another way. You mentioned no human intervention, so perhaps you can use the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/hub/device-identity?view=azure-cli-latest&WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034#az-iot-hub-device-identity-create) to register your device and run that logic in a pipeline/workflow of your choice. You could trigger that workflow when your device is being provisioned/manufactured, depending on your use case.